# Why the webapi's post method is receiving the parameter of type interface as null when called from a postman?

Tags: c#, rest, webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

made this webapi.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] Models.IHero hero)
    {
        Models.Heroes heroes = new Models.Heroes();

        heroes.AddHeroes(hero);
    }
```

calling it from Postman.

```
https://localhost:44320/api/values?Id=1&Name=Shankar
```

but `hero` received in method returns `null`.

Interface:

```
 public interface IHero
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Update:

Converted IHero to Hero class

```
   public class Hero
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and used in the `Post` method.

```
 public void Post([FromBody] Models.Hero hero)
        {
            Models.Heroes heroes = new Models.Heroes();

            heroes.AddHeroes(hero);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) attribute, which means you need to pass data in the body of the Request, but not in Query params
[image]

Comment: did the same now, but still NULL.

Comment: yeah, also follow Serge's answer, use simple class instead of interface for input params. Could you please show us how the Models.IHero looks like?

Comment: hi, I have already pasted that in my questions.

 public interface IHero
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: ok, then just convert it to a class and try again

Comment: I did, check my updated question but now Id is coming 0 and Name = null.

Comment: of course, you should add `public` to properties like: `public int Id { get; set; }`

Comment: done, put in answers box and lemme accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can not use interface since controller should create an instance of input parameter. It can't create instance from interface. So fix your action

```
 public void Post([FromBody] Models.Hero hero)
    {
       var heroes = new Models.Heroes();

        heroes.AddHeroes(hero);
    }
```

Comment: sorry, didn't get it, Models.Hero?

Comment: `FromBody` parameter should be an instance class, interfaces seem to resolve null. Though for lists, the IList interface, `[FromBody] IList<Models.Hero> heroes` should work fine.